# Agenda view with TODO items sorted by deadline and then by scheduled

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to have my TODO items sorted first by deadline and then by scheduled date, while for all the other ones, I honestly don't care. So, let's assume I have the following org file content and assuming it is Thu Nov. 2nd, 2023:

```
 * TODO Deadline in 1d, expected #1
DEADLINE: <2023-11-03 Fri>
 * TODO Deadline in 10d, scheduled in 5d, expected #3
SCHEDULED: <2023-11-07 Tue> DEADLINE: <2023-11-12 Sun>
 * TODO Nothing, expected #4 or #5
 * TODO Deadline in 10d, scheduled in 2d, expected #2
SCHEDULED: <2023-11-04 Sat> DEADLINE: <2023-11-12 Sun>
 * TODO Nothing again, expected #4 or #5
```

I wish I have:

```
 * TODO Deadline in 1d, expected #1
 * TODO Deadline in 10d, scheduled in 2d, expected #2
 * TODO Deadline in 10d, scheduled in 5d, expected #3
 * TODO Nothing, expected #4 or #5
 * TODO Nothing again, expected #4 or #5
```

I tried to implement this custom agenda view

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("b" "Backlog"
        ((todo "TODO"
                ((org-agenda-overriding-header "My to-do list")
                 (org-agenda-block-separator nil)
                 (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
                  '(deadline-up scheduled-up))))))))
```

but I get this:

```
My to-do list
  todo:       TODO Deadline in 10d, scheduled in 2d, expected #2
  todo:       TODO TODO Deadline in 10d, schedule in 5d, expected #3
  todo:       TODO Deadline in 1d, expected #1
  todo:       TODO TODO Nothing, expected #4 or #5
  todo:       TODO TODO Nothing again, expected #4 or #5
```

What am I getting wrong?
Thanks in advance!